# Backup and Restore SQL Server database from higher version to lower version

Tags: sql-server, backup

I'm looking for a way to create a command line script to backup SQL Server 2016 which can be restored in a older version SQL Server 2012.

We have a daily backup from our SQL Server 2016 using the

```
BACKUP DATABASE XXXX TO DISK = "C:\BACKUP.BAK"
```

and this back up is provided to a 3rd party which is running an older SQL Server 2012.

When they use SMSS they get an error stating an error about the incompatible version.

I've tried using `ALTER DATBASE XXXX SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110` ( targeting even a lower than SQL Server 2012 version)... thinking it can be loaded in their 2012 but when they try to load it, it still states that the backup file is in 2016 (v13.xxx) ?!

Sample backup script

```
USE MYDB;
ALTER DATABASE MYDB SET SINGLE_USER

GO  
-- TARGETING SQL Server SQL Server 2012
ALTER DATABASE MYDB SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
GO

BACKUP DATABASE MYDB
TO DISK = 'C:\TEMP\MYDB.BAK'  

ALTER DATABASE MYDB SET MULTI_USER   
GO
```

Can anyone let me know what Im doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just simply **CANNOT** do this - you cannot attach/detach or backup/restore a database from a **newer version** of SQL Server down to an **older version** - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility. And the "database compatibility level" also doesn't help.

You can either get around this problem by

- using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances
- otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (`Tasks > Generate Scripts`) or using a third-party tool
- or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.